# java ThreadLocalRandom fails to produce a specific number within the range

Tags: java, random, numbers

code is this:

```
Long indx = getComboIndex(drawPosCombo,numsize,picksize); //[resolves to the value 1046]
Long cycles = 0l;
Long comboSize = getComboSize(numsize,picksize);  //[resolves to the value 10626]
Long testIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(0, comboSize);

while(testIndex != indx){
    testIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(0, comboSize);
    cycles += 1;
}
```

I'm expecting this to run the while loop until I get a match between indx and testIndex and then continue on.  But, it never leaves the loop :)

I dropped cycles in there to test how many attempts I had tried... after 21 Billion! attempts, it still cannot match the indx value of 1046 from the range of (0,10626).  I stare at it and stare at it but my brain fails to see the issue..  please help :)

debugger shows that it faithfully is creating long values in range.  It boggles my mind that a random generator would not match after this many tries.

Comment: Use `long` not `Long` so that you are comparing values not object references (which might hold the same value)

Comment: Don't use `==` or `!=` to compare objects.

Comment: yes, that was the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> `Long cycles = 0l;`

This is incorrect. You want `long cycles = 0L;`. The capital L is just because lowercase-l is obviously extremely unreadable (looks like a 1), but that's just a style thing. The `long` vs `Long`, that's.. quite a gigantic difference. `Long` is a wrapper object containing a `long` value.

`a == b`, where a and b are `Long` objects, **checks if they are the exact same wrapper object**, not if the values they represent are identical. e.g.:

```
Long a = Long.parseLong("1234");
Long b = Long.parseLong("1234");
System.out.println(a == b); // prints false
```

try it.

There does not appear to be any reason for why you are using the wrapper here. Simply.. don't. Always use `long` unless you really, *really* know what you are doing. The one place where `Long` has to be used is in generics, e.g. if  you have a `new ArrayList<Long>()`, that has to be capital-L long, but then that also belies what is happening: You have these wrappers involved.

Comment: @Unmitigated of course. The point is to illustrate how `Long` is not `long`, I do not understand your comment. The code will print false whether you use `parseLong` or `valueOf` - _that was the point of the example_.